# php NuSoap, giving exception of org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (int -> long)

Tags: php, nusoap, taleo

Greetings to every one.

I am trying to integrate an application with Taleo through WSDL. 
all working good, but in one request we are getting this exception 
this is the submit request suppose to go

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:urn="urn:TBEWebAPI">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:submitCandidate>
  <in0>session-idxxxxxx</in0>
  <in1>48</in1>
  <in2>
    <array>
      <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
      <item>15</item>
    </array>
  </in2> 
</urn:submitCandidate>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

it is giving the error  org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (int -> long)

```
[faultcode] => soapenv:Server.userException
[faultstring] => org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (int -> long)
```

I am using NuSoap. Lemme know if any thing else required for debugging.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try sending the params like

```
$some_ids = array(123 , 1233);
$params = array(  "in0" => $in0,
                  "in1" => $in1,
              "in2" => array('array' => $some_ids ) );
```

Also in `call` , set the last param to `literal` , i believe it should help

Comment: ah perfect, thanks for help. it was the conflict of nusoap and native soap client. thanks Sabeen for guiding.